# Loading a plist into core data after an app update

Tags: iphone, core-data, plist

I have an app which loads a plist data into a core data storage. All the data for the needed for the app is in the plist and is loaded into the core data at the start up of the app.

For the following app updates I was planning to just add items into the plist and update with a new plist but I'm not sure if that is possible as will the core data be able to recognize that there is a change in the plist from which data is parsed from.

Also if there is a better method than the one I am using please do tell.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can put in your plist file a flag and in your code check for that flag. If need to update load the new data to core data.

To do much faster updates you can implement an web service that will return the plist from server. You ask the server if an update is needed and if yes get the new plist from server and the insert it in to core data.